# Python program to manage python script as child

Tags: python

I am looking for a python equivalent of following:

```
until python program.py; do 
    echo "Crashed...Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

Also, I need to kill program.py when the parent program is killed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you modify program.py?

Comment: Hi Nicola, how exactly would you want to modify program.py? See if the answer below (from me) make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modules `subprocess` and `psutil` should provide most (if not all) you need.

```
import sys, subprocess
while True :
    retCode= subprocess.call(["python","program.py"])
    if retCode == 0 : break
    print('Crashed...Restarting...', file=sys.stderr )
```

Comment: Thanks. subprocess will indeed to a trick. I would write a detailed answer with code

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys
import time

Proc = None

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
   ''' Kill the program '''
   os.kill(Proc.pid, sig)
   sys.exit(0)

def main():
   global Proc
   ''' Handle signal on parent program ''' 
   signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

   Proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'program.py'], 
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   while True:
        try:
           wait = Proc.wait()
           if wait:
                if wait != (-1 * signal.SIGKILL):
                    print "Restarting ....(return code %d)" % wait
                    time.sleep(1)
                    Proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'program.py'], 
                                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                else:
                   ''' kill yourself '''
                   sys.exit(0)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # If python >= 2.6 
            # Proc.kill()
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `program.py` I would modify it so that you can call it directly, rather than in a subprocess. If your program follows the convention of containing only definitions and a final executable section to be executed only when it is directly called, i.e. it looks like

```
def do_something():
  pass

def do_something_else():
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  do_something()
  do_something_else()
```

It is sufficient to wrap the last block in a function, such as

```
def main():
  do_something()
  do_something_else()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

At this point you can just import your `program.py` module and call `program.main()`, making your code much simpler.